# Course Files Folder not being created

Tags: desire2learn

I am creating courses using the Valence API.

In DOME we have the d2lTools.CMS.CoursePathEnforced variable set to on.

According to the documentation:

> Path:
>
> > The root path to use for this course offering’s course content. Note that, if your >>back-end service has path enforcement set on for new org units, then you should leave >>this property as an empty string, and the back-end service can populate it for you.

So I am setting the path property to an empty string when I create the course.

However, the folder is never created for the course path, so when users try to add content to a course they get an error. I can't set the path manually because it requires the Org Unit ID of the course, which I don't know till it's created.

Is this a bug or do I have something not configured properly?

Cheers, Iain

Comment: I have successfully tested this call against test LMS instances of LE versions 10.0, 10.1, and 10.2. In all those cases, the CourseEnforcedPath variable was set on for the root org unit. Please note that even though this DOME variable's default value may be 'on', you should double check that for the root org unit the little 'Value' check box is -checked- to make sure it's set as 'on' for the root org's structure.

Comment: When I say I've successfully tested this call what I meant was that the call created a course that _said_ that it had the right content-enforced path in the course record; however, on some platforms it's now evident that this doesn't create the actual path in the storage system, so actually adding content to the course doesn't work. This is a known issue and a fix will appear in a service pack very soon.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample of the JSON structure you should send (note that the CourseTemplateId and SemesterId properties refer to the D2LID values for the course template and semester your new course derives from):

```
{"LocaleId": null, 
 "CourseTemplateId": 1234, 
 "Name": "Extensibility 105", 
 "ShowAddressBook": false, 
 "ForceLocale": false, 
 "StartDate": null, 
 "EndDate": null, 
 "Path": "", 
 "SemesterId": 5678, 
 "Code": "EXT-105"}
```

The create call sends back JSON upon successful creation that looks like this:

```
{"Name": "Extensibility 105",
 "StartDate": null, 
 "CourseTemplate": {"Name": "ExtensibilityTemplate", 
                    "Code": "EXT-TMPL",
                    "Identifier": "1234"},
 "EndDate": null, 
 "Path": "/content/enforced/7531-EXT-105/",
 "IsActive": true,
 "Semester": {"Name": "Spring 2013",
              "Code": "S2013", 
              "Identifier": "5678"},
 "Code": "EXT-105",
 "Department": {"Name": "ExtensibilityDepartment",
                "Code": "1",
                "Identifier": "2468"},
 "Identifier": "7531"}
```

Note that the call allocated an `Identifier` property for the new course, and then incorporated that identity into the enforced content `Path` as one would expect.

Comment: Thanks Viktor, my JSON looks similar to your example. I just re-ran my creation code with the following:

{"Name":"MATHEMATICS",
"Code":"09MAT6",
"Path":"",
"CourseTemplateId":"6722"
,"SemesterId":"6712"
,"StartDate":null,
"EndDate":null,
"LocaleId":"100001",
"ForceLocale":"True",
"ShowAddressBook":"False"}

And the result that came back gives:
... "Path":"/content/enforced/6964-09MAT6/", ...

However, when I browse to the file system, the actual folder created was: /content/enforced/c6a13311-ceaf-46f6-a9cc-debaadf8009d-09MAT6

Any thoughts as to why that would be?

Comment: This sounds to me like a bug: we have a reported defect around the course creation route and the content path on some platforms, so it's possible you're experiencing the same thing. Can you please let me know what back-end service version and service pack you are using?

Comment: Hi Viktor. Thanks for following up. Our LE is V 10.1.0 SP2 and Integration & Middleware Platform is V 1.4.0. Are those the two numbers you need?

Comment: Yes, that is a known issue. A fix has been implemented and will be released in an upcoming service pack for LE v10.1.0 and forward.